# Prove that a power series that is zero on a sequence that converges to zero is the zero function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

I've been trying to solve this problem from Abbott's Understanding Analysis for hours and can't seem to get the last piece of the proof.

> Let $g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x^n$ be a power series that converges for all $x \in (-R,R)$. Let $x_n \rightarrow 0$, while $x_n \neq 0$, and $g(x_n) = 0$ for every $n$. Show that $g(x)$ must be identically zero on $(-R,R)$.

I know that $g(0) = 0$ since $g$ is continuous and the set of zeros of a continuous function is closed. I know that $g'(0) = b_1$, and I need to show that this is zero. I know that if $f(x) = 0$ on an interval, then $f'(x) = 0$ on that interval as well, but I can't seem to find a parallel of that result to this problem.

Comment: Well, there is a theorem which says that if a power series agree on a set with a limit point, then their coefficients are all equal. Has this text taught you something like this yet?

Comment: We have been shown that if $\sum a_n x^n$ = $\sum b_n x^n$ on $(-R,R)$ then the coefficients are equal, but I don't quite see how that would imply what you are saying or how that would help with the problem.

Comment: Well this is part of the standard theorem that zeroes of an analytic function are isolated.

Comment: @EmilioMinichiello What I said is strictly stronger, of course -- one only needs a set with a limit point in $(-R, R)$. How it helps is that the zero power series and the power series you have agree on a set with a limit point if $g(x_n) = 0$ for a sequence $x_n \to 0$ with $x_n \neq 0$. Thus they must be equal!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because we have convergence on a interval around zero, convergence is uniform for both the series and the series of derivatives, and so we can differentiate term by term.

You have
$$
b_1=g'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}=\lim_k\frac{g(x_k)-g(0)}{x_k}=0.
$$ We now have that $$g(x)=x\sum_{n=2}^\infty b_n x^{n-1}.$$ Since $x_n\ne0$ and $g(x_n)=0$, we get that
$$
g_2(x_k)=\sum_{n=2}b_n(x_k)^{n-1}=0
$$
for all $k$. Since $g_2(0)=0$, we may apply the above reasoning again, to obtain $b_2=0$. Now we can repeat the argument to obtain $b_3=0$, $b_4=0$, etc.

Comment: Why would $b_1 \neq 0 \implies g(x) \neq 0$ on some neighborhood of zero?

Comment: @EmilioMinichiello: Use the definition of derivative. If $g'(0)$ is non-zero then the difference quotient $g(x) /x=(g(x) - g(0))/(x-0)$ is also non-zero (has the same sign as that of $g'(0)$) in some neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Ah, of course, thank you!

Comment: Another way to see it is $$b_1=g'(0)=\lim_k\frac {g (x_k)-g (0)}{x_k}=0. $$