# Jameson complex analysis Exercise 1.2.5: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n = s(z)$ is real for all real $z$, prove $a_n$ are real

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

How to solve the following problem? I can't use differentiation to solve it because this exercise is presented before the section that introduces differentiation in the book.

Suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n = s(z)$ for $|z| < R$, where $R > 0$.
If $s(x)$ is real for all real $x$ with $|x| < R$, show that each $a_n$ is real.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: when differentiating a function in $\mathbb{C}$ at a real $x$, you need to account for every way to converge to $x$, but in particular that includes going to $x$ along the real axis.

Comment: @BrunoB Thanks for your answer! But this exercise is presented before the fact that power series are differentiable, so I have to solve this without using differentiation.

Comment: So what facts about power series can you use? Do you have the identity theorem?

Comment: @MartinR We had a 'uniqueness theorem': Suppose that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n = a(z)$
and $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n z^n = b(z)$ for $|z| < R$, where $R > 0$. Suppose, also, that
there are non-zero complex numbers $z_1, z_2, \dots$ such that $z_k \to 0$ as $k \to \infty$ and $a(z_k) = b(z_k)$ for each $k$. Then $a_n = b_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: Could I take any sequence on real axis tending to 0 eg $z_n=1/n$, and $b(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \text{Re}(a_n) z^n$?

Comment: @HIH: That “uniqueness theorem” is the right tool here. I would suggest that you make it clear in the question that this theorem is known to you.

Comment: @HIH I am curious, how do you have this "uniqueness theorem" if you don't know anything yet about differentiating power series ?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I didn't realise it's similar to the Identity Theorem at the first place. The book used induction to prove it: f. Since $a$ and $b$ are continuous at 0, we have
$\lim_{k \to \infty} a(z_k) = a_0$, $\lim_{k \to \infty} b(z_k) = b_0$, $k \to \infty$.
So $a_0 = b_0$. Suppose that it has been established that $a_r = b_r$ for
$r = 0, 1, \dots, m$. Let
$a^*(z) = a_{m+1} + a_{m+2}z + \dots$, $b^*(z) = b_{m+1} + b_{m+2}z + \dots$.
Then $a^*(z_k) = b^*(z_k)$ for each $k$, so, taking the limit as $k \to \infty$,
we have $a_{m+1} = b_{m+1}$. This proves the result.

Comment: Here $a$,$b$ are defined in the previous comment stating the "uniqueness theorem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $s(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n $ and $S(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \overline{a_n} z^n $.

The sequence $(x_k) = (1/k)$ converges to zero, and for all $k$ is  $s(x_k) \in \Bbb R$, so that
$$
 s(x_k) = \overline{s(x_k)} 
= \overline{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \overline{a_n} x^n = S(x_k) \, .
$$

Using the “uniqueness theorem” (that you quoted in the comments) it follows that the power series $s$ and $S$ have the same coefficients, i.e. that $a_n = \overline{a_n}$ for all $n$. But $a_n = \overline{a_n}$ is equivalent to $a_n \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's prove by induction that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$.

For $n=0$, just notice that $s(0)=a_0$, and since $s(0) \in \mathbb{R}$ by assumption, then $a_0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$, and let's assume that for every $0 \leq k \leq n$, one has $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$. Then
$$s(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k z^k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k z^k +z^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_{k+n+1} z^{k}$$

so for every $z \neq 0$, one has
$$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_{k+n+1} z^{k}= \dfrac{s(z)-\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k z^k}{z^{n+1}}$$

In particular,
$$a_{n+1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_{k+n+1} x^{k} =  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  \dfrac{s(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k x^k}{x^{n+1}}$$

and hence $a_{n+1}$ is the limit of a real function, so $a_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$.

This closes the induction and the proof of the property.

Answer (score -1):

$$s(z) = \sum_n a_n z^n \implies s(x) = \sum_n a_n x^n \implies s(x) = \sum_n Re(a_n) x^n + i \sum_n Im(a_n) x^n$$

$$b(x) = \sum_n Im(a_n) x^n  = 0$$ for all $|x| < R$

This implies $Im(a_n) = 0$ i.e., if a real power series is equal to $0$ on an open set then the power series coefficients are uniformly $0$.

See [Prove that a power series that is zero on a sequence that converges to zero is the zero function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2670070/prove-that-a-power-series-that-is-zero-on-a-sequence-that-converges-to-zero-is-t)